# Infinite loop when using useDispatch() and useSelector in the same component

Tags: react-hooks, react-redux, useselector

I am using **React** to develop an app to display a table with a list of orders obtained from a third party API and am managing the states with **Redux**.

I am exploying **useDispacth** to trigger an action which sends a get request to the API and updates the store accordingly.

The action is being dispatched within an **useEffect** hook, which I understand,  calls the action only when the component is rendered. I am also using **useSelector** to get the data from the store. However, when rendering the component, it falls in an **infinite loop** calling the API. When I replace useSelector and use static data, the problem does not happen, therefore, I understand that the **combination** of both, **useDipatch and useSelecter**, is causing the issue.See the code below:

```
const LargeOrders = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(load_large_orders(), [])
    })
    
    const large_orders = useSelector((state)=>state.warehouseData.large_orders) 

    const data = useMemo(()=>[...large_orders],[large_orders])

    const columns = useMemo(()=>[
        
        {
            Header: 'Order ID',
            accessor: 'order_id'
        },
        {
            Header: 'Client Name',
            accessor: 'client'
        },
        {
            Header: 'Order Channel',
            accessor: 'channel'
        },
    ], [])

    const tableInstance = useTable({columns, data});

    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow} = tableInstance;
  
    return(
          ....
    )
}


export default LargeOrders;
```

I will appreciate any suggestion pointing me in the right direction to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your useEffect is configured to run the effect everytime your component is rendered (rather than once when the component is mounted). So when react renders your component it:

- uses the current value of large_orders to determine what JSX to
  return
- executes your effect to update the value of large_orders which (by the selector) will schedule your component to be re-rendered

Since the component has had the redux state updated on each render (by dispatching the action in the effect), and updating the redux state causes the component to be rendered again, you have a loop.

To correct the issue you simply need to ensure that your effect only fires once when the component is mounted. To get this behavior you need to add the dependency array (with nothing in it) to your useEffect call.

e.g.

```
    useEffect(()=>{
            dispatch(load_large_orders(), [])
    }, []) // <--- Note the empty dependency array here
```